# Пропадает курсор в intellij idea

Tags: linux, intellij-idea

Работаю в intellij idea и с недавних пор при вызове меню/подсказок (например alt + enter) стал пропадать указатель, плюс к этому невозможно без него набирать какой-либо код, приходится тыкать мышкой для его возврата.. Раньше такого не было, как это можно исправить или по крайне мере куда копать?

Comment: Самое интересное, что дело скорее всего не в IDE. Ищите проблему в железе и не только. Лично у меня все в порядке. Работаю, как в Windows, так и Linux. Все идеально

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh, странно.. Нигде больше такой проблемы на встречал, тот же clion нормально работает и указатель никуда не девает :( а винде кстати идея тоже себя прилично ведет, только на линуксе проблема

Comment: Вот там и неоходимо искать проблему. В операционной системе, протестить озу. Да много вообще причин может быть. Возможно ломаная версия IDE и т.д и т.п в том роде.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh спасибо